# PermissionError: Forbidden when reading files from aws s3

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, jupyter-notebook, parquet

I am working in python and jupyter notebook, and I am trying to read parquet files from an aws s3bucket, and convert them to a single pandas dataframe.

The bucket and folders are arranged like:

```
The bucket name: mybucket
   First Folder: 123
      Second Folder: Parquets.parquet
        file1.snappy.parquet
        file2.snappy.parquet
        ....
```

I am getting the full path with:

```
bucket = s3.Bucket(name='mybucket')
keys =[]
for key in bucket.objects.all():
  keys.append("s3://mybucket/"+key.key)
```

And then reading them with:

```
count = 0
keys = keys[2:]
for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    subsrc = obj.Object()
    key = obj.key 
    path = keys[count]
    obj_df = pd.read_parquet(path)
    df_list.append(obj_df)
    count +=1
    

df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

But that is giving me:

```
PermissionError: Forbidden
```

pointing to the line 'obj_df = pd.read_parquet(path)'
I know I have full s3 access, so that should not be the issue. Thank you so much!

Comment: Use the aws-cli to make sure you are correct in assuming you have access - `aws s3 ls <PATH>` to list the keys and then `aws s3 cp <PATH> .` to download the object locally

Comment: Would this require downloading the files? I would like to keep the files on the jupyter notebook, not my local computer.

Comment: I know I have access, because I am able to get all of the keys correctly.

Comment: the download is just ensure that you actually do have access. It is possible you have some type of listing access but not read

Comment: I am getting 'bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'' Do you know why this is?

Comment: did you replace the `<PATH>` with an actual path?

Comment: if there are spaces in the path you may need to do something with quotes or escaping

Comment: I Am now getting 'An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied'

Comment: I have access to the data, so I think I need to find a way of getting it without using ListObjects

Answer (score 4):

This is probably because the path to the data is incorrect.

(In the code above, you're doing `pd.read_parquet(path)` where `path = keys[count]`, but I'm pretty sure that that's only the *keys*, which do not include the bucket name. )